# Does MS Edge PDF viewer strip the links in PDF that works in IE for Windows 10 version 1909?

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have reviewed a list of similar postings but I didn't see anything that are specific like my question so I am going to give it a go.

I have a list of master PDF with embedded external links that point to other PDF with a full URL. In MS IE for Win 10, whenever these PDF links are activated in index.html, all the embedded links would appear in the master PDF and connect to the target PDF when called upon.  Without making any changes to the web site and all its files, when the same setup is used in MS Edge ver. 88.0.705.68, none of the embedded links would appear in the same master PDF.  Only the internal links would work and all the external links are vanished (the text are there but not the links).

Just for my own sanity check, I have inspected these master PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017 to make sure all the links (both internal and external) are still there, and they are!  I simply couldn't understand why the same files and setup would work under IE and not under Edge (both Microsoft products)?

Does MS Edge use a different PDF viewer and treat the external links differently than MS IE?

The only workaround is to revert back to IE but given our client's requirements, MS Edge is their preferred browser and I will be most grateful if any tips/recommendations will lead to a solution.

Thank you in advance. IanS

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue in Edge 88.0.705.74. The pdf links embedded in pdf can show and can be opened successfully. You can check the result below. I suggest that you can update your Edge to the latest version to see if the issue still persists.

[image]